# Allow both FTP uploads and php-fpm uploads

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have a centOS 7 server running Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM enabled. Apache runs as normal apache:apache users and in my php-fpm config file for the pool, I have set the user/group and listen user/group to apache:apache

In apache I have a virtual host configured to a user account (/home/site/public) where the user is named "site" - File permissions for the public directory and it's contents are public:apache

With these settings I am able to FTP to the server and upload files as expected, however, the website (WordPress) is unable to upload or change contents (like updating plugins) due to file permissions. The only way I can get this resolved is to change all of the contents of the public directory to apache:apache, allowing WordPress to work as expected, however, now FTP users cannot upload files.

I know it's possible to do both, but I really have no clue what piece of the puzzle I need to change? As I run php-fpm, I expected the listen and user to take on the rights as configured. I first had the user:group in my PHP-FPM pool config defined as site:apache but this made no difference, leading me to believe that the php-fpm pool does not assume the correct user rights?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a group and add both users (ftp and apache), then set permissions to that group:

```
sudo chown -R owner-user:owner-group TARGETWORDPRESSPATH
sudo find TARGETWORDPRESSPATH-type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find TARGETWORDPRESSPATH-type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 TARGETWORDPRESSPATH/wp-config.php
```

The owner-user is probably apache, the owner-group you need to create.